# Loading comboBox from dataset - "Items collection cannot be modified when DataSource property is set"

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, combobox

In my application, I have a model

```
public class LaborCategory
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(10)]
    public string Code { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Rate { get; set; }
    public decimal OnSite { get; set; }
    public decimal OffSite { get; set; }
}
```

I am wanting to create a comboBox (`selectLaborCat`) that has the first option as "Add New Labor Category" (this would be index 0)  then the rest of the list where the selectLaborCat.Value = dataSet.Id and the selectLaborCat.Text = dataSet.Code

I THINK I am getting part of it correct by using

```
        var categories = _context.LaborCategories.OrderBy(c => c.Code).ToArray();

        selectLaborCat.DisplayMember = "Code";
        selectLaborCat.ValueMember = "Id";

        selectLaborCat.DataSource = categories;
```

as this renders the comboBox as I would expect.

But if I try a `selectLaborCat.Items.Insert(0, "Add New Labor Category");` it errors out saying I cannot do Items collection cannot be modified when DataSource property is set

How can I get my "Add New Labor Category" in as index 0 ? I have tried adding the "Add New Category" in as a record in the data set, but I always want it to be index 0 of the comboBox, regardless of how I sort the dataset.

Am I forced to retrieve my dataset as a list, create a new list, add my default "Add New Category" as the first element, then copy the dataset list to the new list and bind the combo box to it like

```
        var categories = _context.LaborCategories.OrderBy(c => c.Code).ToList();
        var comboBoxElements = new List<LaborCategory>();

        var laborCategory = new LaborCategory();
        laborCategory.Id = 0;
        laborCategory.Code = "Add New Labor Category";
        comboBoxElements.Add(laborCategory);


        foreach (var category in categories)
        {
            comboBoxElements.Add(category);
        }

        selectLaborCat.DisplayMember = "Code";
        selectLaborCat.ValueMember = "Id";

        selectLaborCat.DataSource = comboBoxElements;
```

or is there a better way?

Comment: `comboBoxElements.Add(new LaborCategory { Id = 0, Code = "Add New Labor Category" });`

Comment: If you want to keep your list ordered by code and display as first item a insertion prompt then you could simply try to add a prompt that is alphabetically lower than any other code. For example _(Add new ....)_

Comment: Use a button near the `ComboBox` to add items.

Answer (score 0):

Once you add a .DataSource to your listbox, you cannot modify the ListBox.Items collection i.e. after setting `datasource` to the `ComboBox`, Insert/Remove throws exception. A workaround can be, You can add the items to the `ListBox` directly instead of setting a `DataSource`. Then you'd be able to manipulate them directly.

If wanna go with setting DataSource, prepare your data-source, another option can be `BindingList`.

Futhermore, you can use a BindingList object:

- Create a BindingList using your initial items as data Bind your
- List item
- listbox's data source to that BindingList object Add and remove items
  from the BindingList, and not from the listbox

Ref: [Microsoft Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679.aspx)